# Rebus - Rabbitmq map all the objects in specified namespace/assembly

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, castle-windsor, rebus, rebus-rabbitmq

In my application I'm configuring Producer with Rabbitmq.
my configuration looks like below

```
using (var adapter = new BuiltinHandlerActivator())
      {

        Configure.With(adapter)
            .Logging(l => l.ColoredConsole(LogLevel.Warn))
            .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMqAsOneWayClient(connection))
            .Routing(r => r.TypeBased().MapAssemblyOf<TestClass>(queueName))
            .Start();
        await adapter.Bus.Publish(new TestClass() { Name = "TestName123" });
      }
```

**Where in there are many other Dtos i want to map just like TestClass.
Can i specify namespace/assembly in Routing(..)? So that all the objects/dtos under that namespace are mapped?**
Other classes are as below

```
public class TestClass
  {
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Date { get; set; }
  }

public class NewTest 
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

On other side I'm useing WindsorContainer and it looks like below

```
public class Handle : IHandleMessages<TestClass>,IHandleMessages<NewTest>
  {
    Task IHandleMessages<TestClass>.Handle(TestClass message)
    {
      return null;
    }

    Task IHandleMessages<NewTest>.Handle(NewTest message)
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you

```cs
await bus.Publish(new TestClass(...));
```

you don't have to map anything, as PUBLISHING with Rebus will distribute a copy of the event message to anyone who subscribed.

Therefore, to receive the published instance of `TestClass`, your subscribers simply need to

```cs
await bus.Subscribe<TestClass>();
```

This will create the necessary bindings in RabbitMQ, making it so that all published events of that type will be distributed to the subscribers.

I encourage you to go to your RabbitMQ's management console (usually hosted on `http://<rabbitmq-hostname>:15672`) and see what the topology looks like before/after subscribing.

Comment: Yes it worked. also if i go with Routing map and instead of bus.publish i use bus.send and it is also working